# Reading a local URL with docker and selenium

Tags: selenium, docker, dns

I'm in the midst of making a docker container for automation with selenium. At the moment, all I'm doing is reading the title. This is fine for actual live URLs but I want to use my local DNS. I have the following in my local machines /etc/hosts

```
172.31.249.112  site.dev
172.31.249.112  www.site.dev
172.31.249.112  xhprof.site.dev
```

When I run:

```
browser.get('http://site.dev/')
```

I get the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound&u=http%3A//site.dev/&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=Firefox%20can%E2%80%99t%20find%20the%20server%20at%site.dev.
```

How do I make the container somehow resolve my local (host) DNS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because docker has no access to your file,
**Share your /etc/hosts file :**

```
docker run -v /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts your-image
```

Docker-compose :

```
    volumes:
      - /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts
```